# Application legging when fragment changed by Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Having Navigation Drawer by new Support Library

Here is the code

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager;
Fragment fragment;
 fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment= fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.list_view_container);



 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
 if (navigationView != null) {
        setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }
    setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);




private void setupNavigationDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.home:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            fragment = new HomeFragment();
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.list_view_container,fragment).commit();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.current_event:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.college_events:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.national_events:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.workshops:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.trainings:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Launching " + menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.companies:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.talents:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.games:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                    case R.id.submission:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                    case R.id.about:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                }
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

So When I am clicking on `HOME` the fragment is changing but the navigation drawer is legging while closing and also when navigation drawer is pulled back the oping process is hanging as hell in devices which are greater than jellyBean but working really fine in jelly bean and pre jelly bean devices. My application is compiled with latest api that is 23 please help me out.

so when I am removing the fragment changing code than no legging at all.
SO I think something wrong with fragment changing codes.

Comment: It is also likely that the problem comes from the moment Android is creating the fragments. Do you have any pictures to display or online request or any db query in the onCreate or onCreateView of the fragments?

Comment: @JDenais yeah I do have an Picture to display with the drawable attribute in its xml file itself

Comment: Then if the picture is heavy, it is likely that you need to request it on a background thread. A quick AsyncTask is perfect for that.

Comment: @JDenais I removed the picture and the fragment is working fine and starting all the legging is gone but, why this was happen that it was working fine in pre kitkat devices but not in post devices ?

Comment: @JDenais although the image is getting loaded in a blink so I why should I take this in AsyncTask and why this problem occurs in new devices only

Comment: I don't know why the problem does not show on pre-kitkat. Do you use emulators or real devices? do they have the same amount of ram?

Comment: yeah pre kitkat devices were having 512MB RAM and kikat and higher devices were having 1GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `add()` method to change the fragment instead of `replace()` each time when I used to click on NavigationView item, it used to add one new fragment to the activity on each and every click. Well, I asked this question when I was new to android application development.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the drawing of images on the main thread. 
Closing the drawer happens in the same time as creating the Fragment to be displayed. If any operation causes the UI thread to freeze, the drawer stops moving, which is very noticeable.

Any large operation MUST be done in a background thread.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html